# Is the following true regarding the Levi-Civita symbol?

Tags: tensors

Does $ \epsilon_{ipq}\epsilon_{juv} $ equals $ \epsilon_{jpq}\epsilon_{iuv}$?

$i$ and $j$ are dummy, right?

Comment: No this is not true. They only appear once each so they're not dummies.

Comment: I meant dummy in the sense that I can swap them around without changing a thing, were that true.

Comment: $\epsilon_{123}\epsilon_{231}=1\neq 0 = \epsilon_{223}\epsilon_{131}$